# XENYX Q502USB and Neewer NW 700 Mic not working

Tags: voice, recording

As the title says, im using a Behringer XENYX Q502USB mixer and a Neewer NW-700 mic and get no microphone signal on my pc.

What I currently have: I got the mixer plugged in via usb in my pc and the mic via XLR also in the mixer. (phantom power button is pressed down and the red light is on. And 'Gain' is set to 12'o'clock) When I talk in the mic I get no signal on my pc. However the COMP1 and PAN led are turning on.

What I tried: I got the mixer plugged in via usb in my laptop and the mic via XLR to a 48V phantom power supply and from the power supply to the mixer. (Phantom power button is pressed down and the red light is on. And 'Gain' is set to 12'o'clock) and have the exact same results als what I currently have, so no signal but the light are on when talking.

What I also tried: I got the mic plugged in to the 48V Phantom power supply and from the power supply via an XLR to 3.5mm jack cable directly in my pc. And this works fine, however I want it using the mixer.

So can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

Test with a pair of headphones, to take the PC out of the question.

The NW-700 comes with an XLR->3.5mm cable. Find a bin, and put that cable in it. Use an XLR->XLR cable from the mixer to the Mic.

Plug in headphones. Turn the COMP dial to the left fully (no compression).

Phantom Power should be ON.

Level 1 (bottom left) should be set to zero (straight up)

Press the 'To Phones' and 'Main Mix' buttons in - that will send output to the headphones, Main Out and USB.

Set Phones Mix and Main Mix to about seven.

You should now get the mic in your headphones. It should be sending a similar signal to 2-channel USB.

When working, the signal lights above the Main Mix dial should reflect your input.

If you get signal in your headphones, you need to then look at your PC end - but at least you'll know that this setup is working.

Comment: +1 for 'find a bin'. idk why they supply them with that cable & pretend they work without phantom :\